# How to apply a function on two lists of data frames?

Tags: r, list, matrix, dataframe

I have two lists of data frames. Let's call them list_A and list_B.

```
df1 = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(4), nrow=2))
df2 = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(4), nrow=2))
df3 = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(4), nrow=2))
df4 = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(4), nrow=2))

list_A <- list(df1,df2)
list_B <- list(df3,df4)
```

How would I now apply some customized function on the lists in an element wise manner? For example, multiply df1 with df3 and df2 with df4. The function then should take the first two data frames of the lists, define them as matrices and multiply them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `Map` to apply the function on corresponding elements of 'list_A' and 'list_B'

```
Map(`*`, list_A, list_B)
```

As @RHertel mentioned in the comments, if the function needed is `%*%`

```
 Map(function(x,y) as.matrix(x) %*% as.matrix(y), list_A, list_B)
```

Comment: This is gorgeous and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you also for the example with the matrix multiplication. It works perfect.